# HttpMetadataProvider SAML 2.0

Tags: web-services, identity, saml-2.0

can anyone please share some coding samples to implement HTTPMetadataProvider.I have already implemented file based metadata provider using following link
https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/02/reading-metadata-with-opensaml.html

It is very clear and have brief idea to implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSAML contains a metadata provider that can consume SAML metadata from a URL: http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-opensaml2/trunk/src/main/java/org/opensaml/saml2/metadata/provider/HTTPMetadataProvider.java

Learn OpenSAML and use it, don't roll your own.